# Visualizing SOM and adding labels to the map

Tags: python, matplotlib, som

I have been trying to apply SOM on my dataframe, my dataframe has 25 columns where each column represents a house, each house has a values for power consumption for two years, and I want to cluster the data with number of clusters = 3.
I have done the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
%load_ext autoreload

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import plot,axis,show,pcolor,colorbar,bone
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
%matplotlib inline

from minisom import MiniSom
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale, scale
%autoreload 2
data1 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\Tarek\Consumption.xlsx")
data1['h1'] = data1['h1'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h2'] = data1['h2'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h3'] = data1['h3'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h4'] = data1['h4'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h5'] = data1['h5'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h6'] = data1['h6'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h7'] = data1['h7'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h8'] = data1['h8'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h9'] = data1['h9'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h10'] = data1['h10'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h11'] = data1['h11'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h12'] = data1['h12'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h13'] = data1['h13'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h14'] = data1['h14'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h15'] = data1['h15'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h16'] = data1['h16'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h17'] = data1['h17'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h18'] = data1['h18'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h19'] = data1['h19'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h20'] = data1['h20'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h21'] = data1['h21'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h22'] = data1['h22'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h23'] = data1['h23'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h24'] = data1['h24'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1['h25'] = data1['h25'].str.split(';').str[2].astype('float')
data1.fillna(0,inplace=True)
data1=data1.round(decimals=2)
X=data1.values
som =MiniSom(x=3,y=3,input_len=25,sigma=1.0, learning_rate=0.5)
som.random_weights_init(X)
som.train_batch(data=X ,num_iteration=1000,verbose=True)
bone()
pcolor(som.distance_map().T)
colorbar()
markers = ['o' , 's','v']
colors = ['r', 'g','y']
for i, x in enumerate(X):
    w = som.winner(x)
    plot(w[0] + 0.5,
         w[1] + 0.5,
         markers[i],
         markeredgecolor = colors[i],
         markerfacecolor = 'None',
         markersize = 10,
         markeredgewidth = 2)
show()
```

when I am running the code, I am getting this error:
IndexError: list index out of range
please any tips to add the markers and colors in the right way without having any problems, and I would be glad if any one can help, I am a bit new to Python and tried to find a solution but I couldn`t find any.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the length of your `X=data1.values` is around 25 but the length of your `markers` and `colors` is only 3. So in the following for loop, when `i` is 3, you are trying to access `markers[3]` and `colors[3]` which throws an `IndexError` because both `markers` and `colors` goes up to index 2 (indexing starts from 0 in python)

```
for i, x in enumerate(X):
```

One solution is to define custom list of 25 markers and 25 colors. While you might want to define your own  markers, you can leave the `colors` out and let the code choose automatic colors for the `markeredgecolor`

Comment: I added this to my code:
markers = ['o','s','v','^','1','2','3','x','r','*','+','8','>','d','D','X','.','_','M','-','--','<','p','4',',']
and I still have the same problem

Comment: the value of i is 17519 which is the 17519 and the shape of the dataset is (17519,25), so the value of i must be 25 to match the size of the list, how can I solve this problem ?